# Properties file not getting read by Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've spent hours on this. I can't get my variables interpolated correctly with my properties file. I have a properties file and cannot get the values interpolated correctly. I've tried specifying the file explicitly, using an external config and the config inside the jar to no avail.

[image]

## Usage

```
@Component
public class TeradataConnector {
    @Value("${jdbcurl}")
    private String teradataConnection;

    @Value("${jdbctable}")
    private String teradataTable;
```

## Error

```
Jan 05, 2021 6:10:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 05, 2021 6:10:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jan 05, 2021 6:10:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
Jan 05, 2021 6:10:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teradataConnector': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbcurl' in value "${jdbcurl}"
Jan 05, 2021 6:10:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teradataConnector': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbcurl' in value "${jdbcurl}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at com.company.nap.cyclic.App.main(App.java:11) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'jdbcurl' in value "${jdbcurl}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:912) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[cyclic-feature-cyclic_migration-494a9e9-dirty.jar:?]
    ... 17 more
```

## application.properties

```
#### Personalized Batch Configuration
batch.max_records=1
batch.max_wait_seconds=15
jdbcurl=wefwef
jdbcuser=wefwef
jdbcpass=fweijfwef
teradata.table=tester
```

Comment: there is not enough information to tell exactly but are you sure your properties file is in the application's classpath? (is it in the correct place in the JAR/WAR file?)

Comment: What's the required location? I unzipped the jar and I see the files at the root of the unzipped jar.

Comment: I'm using gradle, do I need to explicitly copy them?

Comment: if you are talking about a webapp, they should be inside the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder but being a spring boot app, it could be in the `./resources` folder

Comment: May be take a screenshot of your project structure will help .. If you are using eclipse, expand project explorer and take screenshot

Comment: I've added a picture. The properties are in there.

Comment: if using gradle, ensure your build does not exclude the resources folder

Comment: the properties file should be included inside the `/BOOT-INF/classes` folder of your JAR file

Comment: One thing to try is to annotate your class with `@Configuration` (in the line before or after `@Component`)

Comment: Maybe everything is in the right place but the component is not reading from properties since it's not annotated (not sure this is required but I suppose you can try)

Comment: no luck with @configuration

Comment: I have no BOOT-INF dir when I unzip the jar

Comment: then you need to check how you are building your application... it seems that it is not putting all the files in the right places... I am afraid I know nothing about gradle however

Comment: and to be sure, you added `@Configuration` with capital C, right?

Comment: yes, capital C @Configuration

Comment: import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

Comment: @blurfus I got it working by using the gradle plugin and running bootJar. This created a boot-inf dir in the Jar and now it seems to be finding the correct location

Comment: Nice to know, as I mentioned, there was not enough info to answer the question properly; a grádele setup would have helped here (but I don’t know gradle, what’s needed or how to troubleshoot it) - glad you figured it out

Comment: Thanks for the push. Got me thinking a bit about what I could be missing. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the package containing your main Spring Boot Application file. It contains the static main method and that has the @SpringBootApplication annotation. It should look something like this:

> ```
> @SpringBootApplication
> public class MyApplication {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>   SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);   
> }
> ```

2. Make sure your `TeradataConnector` class resides in a package *beneath* the location of your Spring Application class found in step 1. So if your Spring Application class is in:   `com.companyxyz.invoice`
   then you TeradataConnector class must be: `com.companyxyz.invoice.someotherpackage`

**Note**: It can be further down. In other words, it does not have to be immediately below, just underneath somewhere.

**Reason**: a Spring Boot Application will at startup by default will only scan and autowire components in the packages *underneath* the main Spring Application package. Note: You could also add a @ComponentScan annotation and tell Spring where to find the components if they are not underneath you directory. However, I would recommend just moving them underneath unless there is a strong compelling reason.

Comment: I've checked and the TeradataConnector is indeed below the MyApplication class listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are imported class for `@Value` annotation is `import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value`

`application.properties` file should **inside** `src\main\resources` folder.

You must add **key & value** for `jdbctable` in `application.properties` file which is missing.

Comment: I've found the answer, which I listed in the comments above. The solution is to build using the bootJar task to build an executable jar.